# Using make_int3 vs directly assigning values

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I need to assign values to a variable of type int3(say p) inside a cuda kernel. The assignment is done ~10 times inside the kernel.

```
int3 p;
p = make_int3(a,b,c);

int3 p;
p.x = a; p.y = b; p.z = c;
```

which of the above ways would be better or do both have the same effect in terms of speed ?

I read somewhere(do not remember the source) that make_int3 is a type of constructor, so does directly initializing the values would be better ?

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can benchmark différence using following code and nvvp.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

__global__
void assign_int3(int3* ptr)
{
    int offset = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int3 value = {0};
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        value = make_int3(i, i*2, i*3);
    }
    ptr[offset] = value;
}

__global__
void assign_values(int3* ptr)
{
    int offset = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    int3 value = {0};
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        value.x=i;
        value.y=i*2;
        value.z=i*3;
    }
    ptr[offset]=value;
}

int main()
{
    int3* ptr;
    cudaMalloc(&ptr, 64*1024*sizeof(int3));
    assign_int3<<<1024, 64>>>(ptr);
    assign_values<<<1024, 64>>>(ptr);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaFree(ptr);
}
```

the ptx code generated is the same, so no differences at all, because make_int* methods are inlined.

```
.visible .entry _Z11assign_int3P4int3(
    .param .u64 _Z11assign_int3P4int3_param_0
)
{
    .reg .s32       %r<8>;
    .reg .s64       %rd<5>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z11assign_int3P4int3_param_0];
    cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
    mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
    mov.u32         %r2, %ctaid.x;
    mov.u32         %r3, %ntid.x;
    mad.lo.s32      %r4, %r3, %r2, %r1;
    mul.wide.s32    %rd3, %r4, 12;
    add.s64         %rd4, %rd2, %rd3;
    mov.u32         %r5, 27;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4+8], %r5;
    mov.u32         %r6, 18;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4+4], %r6;
    mov.u32         %r7, 9;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4], %r7;
    ret;
}

.visible .entry _Z13assign_valuesP4int3(
    .param .u64 _Z13assign_valuesP4int3_param_0
)
{
    .reg .s32       %r<8>;
    .reg .s64       %rd<5>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [_Z13assign_valuesP4int3_param_0];
    cvta.to.global.u64      %rd2, %rd1;
    mov.u32         %r1, %tid.x;
    mov.u32         %r2, %ctaid.x;
    mov.u32         %r3, %ntid.x;
    mad.lo.s32      %r4, %r3, %r2, %r1;
    mul.wide.s32    %rd3, %r4, 12;
    add.s64         %rd4, %rd2, %rd3;
    mov.u32         %r5, 27;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4+8], %r5;
    mov.u32         %r6, 18;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4+4], %r6;
    mov.u32         %r7, 9;
    st.global.u32   [%rd4], %r7;
    ret;
}
```

Comment: The (later added) PTX comparison shown here is very instructive, but the "benchmarks"  are total nonsense, and the PTX clearly shows why.  Microbenchmarking requires very carefully constructed code to ensure that the time which is measured is actually related to what being analyzed. These two kernels completely fail at that.

Comment: i'll try to explains my reasonment to justify the source code : 
with benchmarking i've answered the question : "do both have the same effect in terms of speed ?", with the same amount of iterations of the asker (around 10), with an exemple of code he can easily reproduce and run.
Can you please explain why the delta of execution time shouldn't have shown the difference between make_int3(x,y,z) and value.x=x;value.y=y;value.z=z ?

Comment: The compiler has optimised all of your kernel code away (the loop, the original "operations on registers" you mentioned in your first version of this answer) and replaced them with a store of 9,8,27 to global memory. There are more total instructions and latency in calculating the index of the writes than anything else in that PTX code. It isn't a representative benchmark of anything. And the way the lazy context establishment works in recent CUDA versions, I would guess that the `assign_int3` call will own  rather a lot of startup overhead and profile to be slower, even with *identical* PTX.